# Security for applications hosted in kubernetes ingress

Tags: security, kubernetes

I need to host the frontend and backend parts of my application on ingress kubernetes. I would like only the frontend part to be sent to the backend part, even though both are available in ingress under one host (but a different path). Is it possible to set something like this in a kubernetes cluster? So that no other applications can send requests to the backend part. Can you do something like this with kubernetes security headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the cluster, you can restrict traffic between services by using [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). E.g. you can declare that service A can send traffic to service B, but that service C can not send traffic to service B. However, you need to make sure that your cluster has a [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) with support for Network Policies. [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/) is an example for such add-on.

Ingress is useful for declaring what services can receive traffic from outside of the cluster.

Also, Service Meshes, like [Istio](https://istio.io/) is useful for further enhance this security. E.g. by using an Egress proxy, mTLS and require JWT based authentication between services.